# How POST parameters to server?

Tags: robotframework

I want to send some parameters to server by using "Robot framework".

I wrote code just like below.

```
*** Setting ***
Library    REST   myserver.com

*** Variable ***
&dict = auth_key=******

*** Test Cases ***
Send Auth Key and Get Access Token.
    POST    /auth    ${dict}
    Integer    response status    200
```

But server receives no params.

How I correct code?

Thanks.

Comment: What library is this? It looks like this one - https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-restlibrary/ - which is long abandoned. If so, you'll be better off with something much more popular, for example this one: https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using REST library it is not being updated anymore. I would suggest to use Request-Library it is built on top of the requests library in python.

Here is a example of a Post request with Json data.

```
  Post Requests with Json Data
        [Tags]  post
        Create Session  httpbin     http://httpbin.org
        &{data}=    Create Dictionary   latitude=30.496346  longitude=-87.640356
        ${resp}=     Post Request  httpbin  /post    json=${data}
        Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
        ${jsondata}=  To Json  ${resp.content}
        Should Be Equal     ${jsondata['json']}     ${data}
```

Change your test case to:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  RequestsLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
Send Auth Key and Get Access Token.
    Create Session    Gateway    https://URLHERE  
    &{dict} = Create Dictionary   auth_key=******
    ${resp}=     Post Request   Gateway   /auth    json=${dict}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
```

Comment: OK. I'm going to  use RequestsLibrary. Thank you your answer.